# How to read excel file datas in webforms - hosted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a small project in VS-2015 asp.net - c#, to read excel file data's. When I run it as localhost it's working fine. But after hosting to FTP, it's not working, giving error like

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

My Connection String - XLSX file

```
String MyExcelFile = Server.MapPath(MyInput1.PostedFile.FileName); // Not Working
String MyExcelFile = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath(MyInput1.PostedFile.FileName)); // Not Working

String MyExcelFile = MyInput1.PostedFile.FileName; // Working good in localhost
```

But giving error after published to FTP.

```
String StrConn2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + MyExcelFile + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; \"";

String MyExcelSheet = "[Sheet1$]";
String  MySQLSelect = "select * from " + MyExcelSheet;
```

Comment: one thing i need to know, r u able to login remote login (RDP) to your ftp server ?

Comment: Yes, I can login , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because of Microsoft office(Excel) not installed on server. so you need to install microsoft office (Excel) or [install Microsoft Access Database](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) on server.

For download Microsoft Access Database go to : https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255